# store user entered mail id to separate table

Tags: users, 9

Have a requirement to develop drupal 9 custom module to get the mail id from the user registration form and store it separate table. I tried the hook_user_presave function to get the mail id but was not able to get it. Hereby sharing the code

```
function save_mail_user_presave(UserInterface $user)
 {

     try{
                $conn = Database::getConnection();
                $fields["mail"] = $user->get('mail')->value;
            $conn->insert('save_email')
                           ->fields($fields)->execute();
                  \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t(' Thank you !! Your>

        } catch(Exception $ex){
                \Drupal::logger('save_email')->error($ex->getMessage());
        }

}
```

Anybody helps me figure out the problem

Comment: The question should explain what *was not able to get it* means. Do you mean that, with the code you are using, `$fields["mail"]` doesn't contain the user email? Do you get any error message? Which one?

Comment: As side note, there are two errors in the shown code: `$this` cannot be used outside a class method, for example inside a function; the literal string passed to `$this->t()` doesn't have the last string delimiter. Verify the code you are using is correct PHP code and be sure you correctly copied the code in the question.

Comment: Yes not able to catch the email address on .$fields["mail "] Empty. Not getting any error.Thanks

Comment: See my second comment. If you are really using that code, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 9 already stores the email address upon registration in the `init` column of the `users_field_data` table.  This is the "email address from the user registration form"; it is different from the user's account email address, which is stored in the `mail` column of the same table.

So, there's no need for a custom module for this; you can use the `column` that Drupal already provides.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I want catch the email address even at the invalid form values. Can u suggest way to address this

Comment: @srini In that case, you cannot use `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave()` as that hook is invoked when the submitted values passed validation. It's not clear why you would store the email address when the form doesn't pass validation. In that case, you would end up storing multiple emails for a single user, even an empty string.

Comment: Want to capture for same analysis purpose. Is there any way to capture that. If presave  function not works means Please suggest